# Statsmodels GLM binomial distribution: manual calculation of the null log-likelihood

Tags: python, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, likelihood, statsmodels

For my better understanding, I'm trying to calculate manually the log-likelihood that statsmodels GLM is reporting in the summary results. However, my manual calculation does not match the result that I see in the summary.

Let's take for example the null log-likelihood from the GLM model applied to the the star98 dataset used in the [statsmodel example pages](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html) in which the binomial distribution was applied.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = sm.datasets.star98.load()
data.exog = sm.add_constant(data.exog, prepend=False)
glm_binom = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog, family=sm.families.Binomial())
res = glm_binom.fit()
```

```
# Null log-likelihood given by the statsmodels GLM results
res.llnull
```

gives a value of -18131.91.

To calculate that manually I used the formula that I found at slide 23 of [this presentation](https://federicovegetti.github.io/teaching/ecpr_glm/slides/GLM_slides_Day2.pdf) and that I copy here:

[image: Log-likelihood formula for a binomial]

I then replaced Xi*Beta with res.null because in the case of the null-model this is the constant prediction.

The formula translated into python is then the following:

```
np.sum((yi)*res.null) - np.sum(np.log(1+np.exp(res.null)))
```

Then the question is: what is exactly yi? I would assume that's the ratio between NABOVE and total number of cases i.e. NABOVE + NBELOW.

```
yi = data.endog['NABOVE']/(data.endog['NABOVE']+data.endog['NBELOW'])
```

In other words the success/fail rate that the model is trying to predict. But if I apply that, then the result is very far from what I read out of the res.llnull printout.

What's wrong in what I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The null likelihood is computed using the marginal estimate of the mean of the outcome.  In other words, it is the negative log likelihood of a model with a single parameter (namely, the intercept).

Here is how to compute the null likelihood using python and a comparison with `statsmodels`

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tools import add_constant
from scipy.special import expit

# Simulate some data
x = np.random.normal(size = 100)
X = add_constant(x)
eta = -2 + 0.8*x
p = expit(eta)
y = np.random.binomial(p=p, n=1)

# Fit the model
fit = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()
fit.summary()

marginal_p = y.mean()

# Here I am computing the likelihood using a model with a single parameter
# I know that p will just be the average of the ys in this model
nLL = (np.log(marginal_p)*y + np.log(1-marginal_p)*(1-y))

# Does not yield an exception, so this must be true.
np.testing.assert_allclose(nLL.sum(), fit.llnull)
```

I don't see you computing the average if the y in your solution, which si probably the source of the error.

Comment: While I understand and follow your example, I still don't get the numbers match with my dataset. I added the code I'm using in my original question.
I assume the problem lies in what I assign to yi but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @GianlucaColangelo Well to start, I don't see any methods in the fitted mode corresponding to `null`.  All I see is `res.llnull`, and that isn't the marginal probability its the log likelihood of the null value.  So let's start with this: What is `res.null` supposed to give you

Comment: [res.null](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults) it's an array representing the fitted values of the null model. So all elements of the array are equal and basically representing y.mean(). So what you call marginal_p in your example. Actually, despite being close the two quantities are not exactly the same so I could replace the above formula with this one: `np.sum((y)*y.mean()) - len(y)*(np.log(1+np.exp(y.mean())))` but the result is still pretty much the same.